# Routing Mvc3 value of datepicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing, telerik-mvc

i am working in an asp Mvc3 with telerik
I added a new route in my Global.asax

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "SearchDate",
            "ahmed/{date1}/{date2}",
            new
            {
                controller = "ListeDernierEmplacementConnu",
                action = "Search",
                date1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                date2 = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

and in My view i would use this (datepicker form) to send dates to the controller

```
    @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("SearchDate", new { date1 ="1-01-2012", date2 ="1-07-2012"}))

   {
            <label for="date1">rechercher entre</label>
            @(Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
                    .Name("date1")
                   .Value(DateTime.Now).Max(DateTime.Now).Min(("01/01/2012"))
            )
            <label for="date2">et</label>
            @(Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
                    .Name("date2")
                   .Value(DateTime.Now).Max(DateTime.Now).Min(("01/01/2012"))
            )

    <button type="submit" class="t-button t-state-default" value="search">Rechercher</button>
   }
```

Everything works fine i get the 2 values of datepicker in my controller
but i'm always redirected to the same URL localhost/ahmed/1-01-2012/1-07-2012?Grid-page=1

for example in datepicker1 i put 1/1/2012  datepicker2 2/2/2012

in view i get what i want : 1/1/2012 , 2/2/2012

but the url is static i get always: localhost/ahmed/1-01-2012/1-07-2012?Grid-page=1

how to dynamically change this 2 values in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could post your form to another controller action and redirect to the appropriate place within this method.

I've prepared an example for you below:

**Form**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RedirectToDate", "YourController"))
{
<label for="date1">rechercher entre</label> 
    @(Html.Telerik().DatePicker() 
            .Name("date1") 
            .Value(DateTime.Now).Max(DateTime.Now).Min(("01/01/2012")) 
    ) 
    <label for="date2">et</label> 
    @(Html.Telerik().DatePicker() 
            .Name("date2") 
            .Value(DateTime.Now).Max(DateTime.Now).Min(("01/01/2012")) 
    ) 


<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult RedirectToDate()
{

    string date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["date1"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    string date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["date2"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

    return Redirect(String.Concat("/ahmed/", date1 "/", date2 "/"));
}
```